# IKEv2: Why is it important "that each side sign the other side's nonce"

Tags: digital-signature, ipsec, nonce, ike

I am currently diging deep into the IKEv2 protocol. In the description of the Authentication (RFC5996, p. 48), the following statement is given:

"It is critical to the security of the exchange that each side sign the other side’s nonce"

Can anyone explain this issue to me?
It is clear to me, that I need *some* kind of signature to prove the knowledge of a secret in order to authenticate. Also the fact that each side signs their first complete IKE_SA_INIT packet to provide integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence you quote is about [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). If two systems *A* and *B* run the protocol and *B* proves its identity by signing some data element *x*, then that value *x* must change in some way every time the protocol is played. Otherwise, if *x* is reused, then an attacker *C* may impersonate *B*, by first observing the protocol once (to get a copy of *B*'s signature on *x*), then by claiming to be *B* and showing that signature value again.

So *x* must change each time; and *A* must be sure that *x* is a new value, so it must not be chosen by *B*, but by *A*. A value chosen anew for each protocol run by a party and sent to the other is called a *nonce*.

The symmetrical situation arises when *A* signs and *B* verifies, so you need two nonces, and each system must sign the other side's nonce.

---

A simple nonce is not enough, though, because some industrious attacker could do the following:

- *C* connects to *A* and claims to be *B*.
- Simultaneously, *C* connects to *B* and claims to be *A*.
- *A* sends a nonce *u* to be signed by *C* (*A* will verify it with *B*'s public key).
- *B* sends a nonce *v* to be signed by *C* (*B* will verify it with *A*'s public key).
- *C* sends *u* to *B* as the nonce to be signed by *B*.
- *C* sends *v* to *A* as the nonce to be signed by *A*.
- *B* signs *u*, as is specified by the protocol.
- *A* signs *v*, as is specified by the protocol.
- *C* sends *B*'s signature on *u* to *A*.
- *C* sends *A*'s signature on *v* to *B*.

And voila! both *A* and *B* received a signature from, respectively, *B* and *A*, on the nonce values *u* and *v* that they sent. So now *A* and *B* are "sure" to be talking to each other, while in fact they are talking to the attacker *C*.

The trick here is that *C* "retargets" nonces and signatures: the attacker sends as "nonce to sign" the value that he received himself, and also sends back as "signature on nonce" a signature that he received. To prevent such attacks, the signature must not cover *only* the nonce, but also enough connection-specific data to prevent this retargeting. That is the point of including the whole IKE_SA_INIT in that block which is signed.

This kind of protocol issue is generic; you'll find the same kind of countermeasures in [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), where both the signature from the client (`CertificateVerify`) and the final checksums (`Finished` messages) operate on hashes computed over all previous handshake messages.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for also explaining why it is important to sign the IKE_SA_INIT!